# AddressBook with Automatic Reference Counting

Tags: iphone, automatic-ref-counting, addressbook

Hi I have the following piece of code:

```
ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue([people objectAtIndex:i], kABPersonPhoneProperty);
```

I'm getting an error saying that there is no matching function for call to `ABRecordCopyValue`. I'm using automatic reference counting and I'm almost certain thats why I'm getting this error. At this point in development it will be a paint to revert to normal reference counting.

Anyone know a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you have imported the libraries needed?

Comment: I imported <AddressBook/AddressBook.h> and 
<stdlib.h> and I also added the AddressBook framework

Answer (score 0):

Please try below

```
ABRecordRef people = ABPersonCreate();

ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(people,kABPersonPhoneProperty);
```